# Changing class from python 3 to python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Okay so i am trying to learn python from a book that teaches you by instructing you on how to make a text based adventure game. The only problem is that I use python 2.7 and the book is made in python 3. I have been able to get by so far but I rand into a problem with this code.

```
class Person :
    age = 15
    name = "Rolf"
    favorite_foods = ["beets", "Turnips", "Weisswurst"]

    def birth_year() :
        return 2015 - age
```

I don't want you to fix it I just want you to tell me whats different about this that I have to change to get it to work with 2.7 so I can fix it myself.

Comment: I strongly recommend either upgrading to 3.X or finding a 2.7 tutorial. Attempting to use one to learn the other will result in a lot of pain and frustration without much payoff.

Comment: That code would not work in any version of python, it would need  `return 2015 - Person.age`

Comment: If the book is telling you to store name and age as class variables, throw it out and find a real book.

Comment: that's not a class, that's a namespace. It's missing the _ _init _ _ method and the "self" reference. Use this book to press stuff instead of reading it.

Answer (score 0):

While I would agree with the above comments that this book seems highly suspect, I can offer a bit of a hint as how to move forward.

1. Remember that classes are intentionally dynamic, constant variables are fine, but do your initialization inside an `__init__():` function.
2. Object functions need the object passed to them, class functions need the class passed to them.  [This](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods) is an excellent resource on how you should be using functions inside classes. `def birth_year(self):` is a good place to start
3. Finally, variables are only defined inside their scope. Long story short, you wont be able to fine `age` outside of the class. Use the dot operator to indicate that something falls within a specific scope. In the context, try `self.age` assuming you've figured out recommendation 2.

Hope this helps you get started! Best of luck, objects can be a bit tricky to wrap your head around at first.